# Export a Multipass-VM to a .QCOW2 file

Tags: virtualbox, cloud-init, qcow2, multipass

I was working with `Multipass` to create a VM machine of Ubuntu Bionic. I have made a lot of changes to the initial installation (one includes kernel changes) and that's why I would like to export in a QCOW2 image, because I need to recreate this image in the Google Cloud Platform. From this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180895/import-export-vms-from-multipass) with a similar topic, Christopher Townsend said that there were not a easy way to do it, but maybe there is a "hard" way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this question in the issues from the Github repository of the project, they are trying to work in a enhancement to be able to create snapshot or backups from the virtual machines created. There is a open issue who talks about this theme here if you want to know which is the status of the improvement of the application.

[Multipass Github](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/208)