# use existing multipass image

Tags: multipass

I migrated my files from my old x86 Macbook Pro to my dazzling M1 Mac.  I did not migrate any applications, because I don't want to use the Rosetta technology to run x86 binaries in emulation.

I installed Multipass, no problem.  But I have no access to my old multipass VMs, even though the directories are right where they always were.

What I want to do is "attach" the existing VMs to multipassd, so I can start them.

I've looked at the json files in **/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances**:

```
multipassd-vm-instances.json
vault/multipassd-instance-image-records.json
```

These files are identical to those on the old machine.

I *seems* like a simple problem?  Someplace, multipass must maintain a list of VMs.  (Evidently, in more than one place, because the json files show the names of the existing VM directories.)

The one relevant answer I found on StackOverflow related to Linux, not MacOS, and suggested the solution was just a matter of editing the json files.  Since mine look OK, I'm betting there's more to it than that.

Comment: At the moment, import/export of VM guests is not supported and perhaps not even possible at all. [Previous AskUbuntuquestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180895/import-export-vms-from-multipass), [Discourse question from within the past week](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/can-i-backup-the-multipass-image/32533)

Comment: This can't work, because of the change of CPU architecture. On your old machine, certainly a x86 version of Ubuntu was installed while your new machine an ARM version will be used.